# Clang performs better than MSVC on Windows

Tags: visual-c++, clang, compiler-optimization

The c++ code compiled by clang runs a lot faster than the same code compiled by MSVC. And I checked the ASM code, found out that clang automatically uses SIMD instructions for speed purposes. So I rewrite the main calculation part by using AVX Intrinsics code. Still, the program compiled by Clang gains a 10% benefit of speed.
Is it common sense that Clang performs better than MSVC on Windows? Or I missed some important optimization configurations of MSVC.

I've tested these code:

```
static __inline int RGBToY(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b) {
  return (66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b + 0x1080) >> 8;
}

void ToYRow_C(const unsigned char* src_argb0, unsigned char* dst_y, int width) {
  int x;
  for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    dst_y[0] = RGBToY(src_argb0[2], src_argb0[1], src_argb0[0]);
    src_argb0 += 3;
    dst_y += 1;
  }
}
```

And the compiling flags for Clang: -O2 -mavx2, flags for MSVC: /O2 /arch:AVX2.
Processing a 2560x1440 image on a clang-compiled program costs 1.2ms, and 4.2ms for a MSVC-compiled program.

Comment: What optimizations are you enabling for clang and MSVC?  In particular, have you tried using /arch:AVX2 on MSVC?

Comment: I used -O2 for clang and MSVC. Yes, I tried  /arch:AVX2 on MSVC, but MSVC didn't generate SIMD instructions under this flag.

Comment: can you include the actual code you are referring to and the different compiler and linker settings?

Comment: thanks for your attention, code attached.

Comment: That's normal; it's a known fact that MSVC is *usually* not as good at optimizing as clang or GCC.  https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=88&sid=c0353906066d6d729db48f5274f2aff7  Occasionally it does better, but usually worse, including at auto-vectorization.  Cases involving 8-bit and 16-bit integers, especially wider temporaries, are tricky for compilers.

Comment: For packed data like this, you might split it into "rg" and "b" chunks, for use with `pmaddubsw` to multiply and add within 16-bit chunks.  (It would be more convenient if we could get the `g` by itself in a 16-bit chunk cheaply, like with a `pshufb`, since `129` doesn't fit in signed 8-bit for `pmaddubsw`.  Maybe handle it as `(g<<7) + g` or just a separate multiply.  Or use `-127` as a coefficient for `g` in `pmaddubsw` and add it in left-shifted by a byte to get `129*g = 256*g + (-127*g)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems MSVC is highly sensitive to variations in loop structure and exect form of increment of induction vars. I opened an issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/CC-Slight-variations-in-loop-struct/10370710), maybe something can change.

[Edit:]
If you somehow separate src_argb0 into 3 input streams, MSVC handles it much better:

```cpp
static __inline int RGBToY(unsigned char r, 
                           unsigned char g, 
                           unsigned char b) {
  return (66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b + 0x1080) >> 8;
}

void ToYRow_C(const unsigned char* srcr,
              const unsigned char* srcg,
              const unsigned char* srcb, 
              unsigned char* dst_y, 
              int width) {
  for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    dst_y[x] = RGBToY(srcr[x], srcg[x], srcb[x]);
  }
}
```

You can compare the resulting code for MSVC and clang in [this godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3bPxnMWj4).

Comment: With AVX2 available for your planar version (https://godbolt.org/z/93WjoTWYc - `clang -O3 -march=skylake` vs. MSVC `-O2 -arch:AVX2`), MSVC does vectorize, but doesn't do as good a job as clang.  It might still be acceptable for many use-cases, but notice that clang uses 1-uop `vpmaddwd` on 32-bit integers that were zero-extended from 8-bit, vs. MSVC using `vpmulld` 32x32=>32-bit multiplies that run as 2 uops on Intel.  Also, clang optimizes away the `>>8` into the byte shuffling it has to do anyway to re-pack.

Comment: For 32 bytes of output (one ymm store), clang used 12 `vpmaddwd`, 4x `vpshufb` -> 2x `vpackusdw` -> 2x `vpermq` -> 1x `vpackuswb` -> 1x `vpermq`.  So a total of 10 shuffles, some able to run on port 1 as well as 5 on Ice Lake.  But for 8 bytes of output (1/4 the work per iteration), MSVC used 6x `vpmulld`, so twice as many multiplies per byte, and on Intel CPUs 4x as many multiply *uops* per output byte.  And 4x `vpshufb` + 1x `vpermq`.  MSVC strangely chooses to reload the `vpshufb` constants every iteration.

Comment: https://uica.uops.info/ predicts clang's version running 21.78 cycles / iter on Skylake, 18.36 c/i on Ice Lake.  So 0.68 c/byte or 0.57 c/byte of output.  vs. MSVC at 14 cycles / iter on SKL or 12.18 on ICL.  So 1.75 c/B or 1.52 c/B of output over large buffers for planar data (at least if L2 cache or maybe L3 to keep up with memory bandwidth). So on Skylake, clang is 2.57x as fast (MSVC takes 2.57x as long to run), on Ice Lake it's 2.65x faster.  AMD wouldn't be as bad, having single-uop `vpmulld`, but I haven't figured out why MSVC takes twice as many multiply instructions.

Comment: Even clang isn't optimal; with planar data we can probably use `pmaddubsw` to do 8x8 => 16-bit multiplies after zero-extending, or maybe just `pmullw` which works for the `129` coefficient as well (which doesn't fit in signed 8-bit), to have twice the data density and less re-packing work.  Also, `vpmovzxbd` unpacking by widening takes more work to re-pack than slicing up with shift/mask (e.g. taking the 1st or 2nd byte of every 2-byte or 4-byte chunk, so data doesn't have to move far horizontally).